# Changing mouse cursor in Share Point

Tags: sharepoint, mouseevent, mouse-cursor

I designed a Share Point page in Share Point Designer. ( I cannot upload anything to the servers or no chance to use add-ons)

Since it is requested  I have to change the shape of mouse cursor. Some purple bubbles or a logo should follow the original mouse cursor when I move the mouse.

How can do this? If I find the code where (in which file) should I put it?
Can it be done with site based design?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well first, don't. I can't think of a single situation where changing the cursor is a good idea for a web page. However if you find yourself compelled by an employer who you can't talk out of it, unfortunately the only way I can think about going about it is modifying the master page for the whole front end server. You'll have to make the changes on every front end server if you run a farm.

Comment: Using SharePoint designer you don't need to worry about propagating files across web servers as changes go into the content database. However, you do need to apply changes seperately on each site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a a Content Editor Web Part to every page that requires a change to the mouse cursor and insert your JavaScript in there.

If you had permission to install software on the SharePoint server then you could use our free [SharePoint Infuser](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Infuser-(Free).aspx) to automatically add your code to every page.

You may be better off telling your employer that it is not possible. This is not 1995 any more :-)